# How to detect HTTP status from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http, dom

I want to detect in a script, which could be deployed beyond my control, whether the page was delivered with a HTTP status of 200, 404 or 500 etc.

This can't be done, right?

Comment: You could look at the page contents to see if it contains phrases like "not found" or "error", but that's probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have the page make a XMLHttpRequest to itself (using `location.href` or `document.URL`) and check the HTTP status you get. Seems to be pretty portable way to me. Why you would do a thing like this is beyond my understanding though ;)

Comment: Yes this is the solution I ended up going for - additionally I made a HTTP HEAD request to forestall having the client download the entire page twice.

Why I want to do this? Think a .js file that I'm writing for website administrators to install on their website.

Comment: This is dangerous, because the second request might alter the server in unexpected ways (but double-POSTing the page), etc.
Also, the same request might succeed once, but fail the next time.

Comment: I'm confused, neither @EoghanM or me mentions POST. He even says he used HEAD. Using GET or HEAD should be safe as they are idempotent methods and should not cause side-effects.

Comment: "Why you would do a thing like this?" - because your 404 page is the same as another page, and you want to handle the small differences on the client. ;)

Comment: I want to set the `<base href>` when the page is a 404, so I need to do this early and synchronously.  Annoying if it will slow down when the page is a 200 though.

Answer (score 1):

Page A can be a Javascript that loads page B via AJAX and displays it with
document.write or in a pop up window or however.

In such a strategy, you can check return code for success/failure in the AJAX handler and send different things to the output window depending on status.

Most Ajax libraries provide a way to examine the return code....

See for instance "transport.status" with Ajax.Request in Prototype.js

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track with transport.status - ideally I'd like to avoid another HTTP request, but maybe this is the only way?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to know if this is the ONLY way or not. If you use the answer I gave, you will also need to obey Javascript's security model and fetch pages ONLY from the same site.  This can be gotten around, though, by clever uses of proxies.

Answer (score -2):

Why does the javascript need to know this?  Sounds like it would make more sense just to embed it on a custom 404 page.  No need to detect HTTP status of the parent page (I don't think it's possible - maybe doing an ajax call to itself after each load, but that's just silly).  if the code is being executed, its guaranteed to be a 404

Comment: I can't create a custom 404 page as the script is 'being deployed beyond my control' - I'm not making the HTML and the 404 page won't be on my site :)

Comment: Making a browser extension and running into the same issue - if the current URL 404s and is a misspelling of a common page on a certain site, I'm trying to redirect to that page. 

I'm going with the AJAX solution, since I don't believe a page's deletion status would change often in the milliseconds between the first and second request.

Answer (score -3):

I recently found how to do it (credits to : [hunlock](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/AJAX_for_n00bs))

AJAX.getAllResponseHeaders() -- returns as a string all current
headers in use.
AJAX.getResponseHeader("headerLabel") -- returns value of the
requested header.