# Get current page http status from javascript

Tags: javascript, http

Is there any way to get the http status of the current web page from javascript?

Spent some time searching on the web, but no luck at all... Seems like it's not possible, but wanted to check with Stack Overflow for maybe some fancy workaround.

(Providing it from the server as part of the response body is not acceptable, the status is supposed to be only available via the http header)

Comment: well, given that your JS is executed at all, I suppose the http response code was 200 OK?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin That's but one of many possibilities

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin You could have a custom 404 page with some special javascript..

Comment: 304 is also an acceptable status code to get javascript running

Comment: I've never bumped into anything on the navigator, document or window object that would solve this... It seems like you'd have to ping the server with an Ajax call or something

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that. anyway, I think that's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837064/how-to-detect-http-status-from-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect HTTP status from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837064/how-to-detect-http-status-from-javascript)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is not in any way possible, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

This is (*experimental but*) possible in chrome by leveraging [responseStatus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/responseStatus) from Performance API. We look for the `navigation` entryType which should provide the page http status.

```
const navigationData = window.performance.getEntries().find(e => e.entryType === "navigation")
navigationData.responseStatus // 200
```

Alternative:

```
const navigationData = window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0];
navigationData.responseStatus // 200
```

Comment: Note that instead of `window.performance.getEntries().find(e => e.entryType === "navigation")` you can just do `window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')`

Comment: `.find` returns the first element found, while `getEntriesByType` returns an array, so we'd need to look at index `[0]`. Have updated answer with the alternative. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(window.performance.getEntries()[0].responseStatus)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

###### Yes You can

Simply request the same page, i.e. URI, using the `XMLHttpRequest`. Suppose that your page on `/stop.php` in `stop.php` you may do something like:

```
<script>
function xhrRequest(){            
            console.log(this.status);
            // Do some logic here. 
        }
function getReq(url){
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.addEventListener("load", xhrRequest);
            oReq.open("GET", url);
            oReq.send();
        }
getReq("/stop.php");
</script>
```

Checkout this [DEMO](https://codepen.io/saidbakr/pen/gOoXeXQ)

#### Note:

> You have to note that, it is a copy of the page not the page itself.
> I, already, have used this solution on a page in which the server may
> generate Forbidden HTTP status code when the request is come from
> unauthorized IP address, so the condition here is very simple and
> there is no much difference between the original and the copy page
> that you have simulate its visit.

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner:

```
fetch(location.href).then(response => console.log(response.status));
```

This is asynchronous, if you need a synchronous solution use `XMLHttpRequest` (as in the other answer) together with [async: false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#parameters) or use `async/await` which feels synchronous, but is still asynchronous under the hood.

Attention: There is the potential risk that the status code of this new request isn't the same as the status code of the original page request, for several reasons, like timouts, authentication and so on.

**Alternatively**

An approach without an extra call would require to include the status code in the page on the server side, then read it on the client side via JavaScript, like so:

Java + Thymeleaf + meta tag:

```
<meta name="statuscode" th:content="${#response.status}">
```

Java + Thymeleaf + JavaScript variable:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  const statusCode = [[${#response.status}]];
</script>
```

PHP + meta tag (unverified):

```
<meta name="statuscode" content="<?php echo http_response_code() ?>">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', window.location.href, false);
xhr.send(null);
console.log(xhr.status);
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34564705)

Comment: And it's not really the status of the current page as you're making a new request.

Comment: And using XHR is basically already covered in another answer.

Answer (score -4):

It is not beautiful, but you can use:

```
t = jQuery.get(location.href)
    .success(function () { console.log(t.status) })
    .error(function()    { console.log(t.status) });
```

That When Eric says, this solution will make a new request from the same paga, and not show status of current request.

Comment: Incorrect: this code makes a new requests, it doesn't get the status of the page as it is currently loaded in the browser. As of 2018, there's no way to get the error status of the currently loaded HTML page for any page.