# Determining the HTTP status code of the initial request in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, http, amazon-s3

I've got S3 set up for static hosting with a custom error page. Is there any way of knowing the HTTP status code? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript) but it's more about headers than HTTP status code.

I'm aiming at pure JS answers but if there's an S3-specific way of getting this that I've missed please let me know :)

Comment: [Like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654390/get-current-page-http-status-from-javascript), sorry

Comment: Damn, how did I miss that! Yeah that's it, thanks :P