# Can response code be accessed from parent window?

Tags: javascript, window.open

If I run `window.open(..)` is it possible to get response code of this new window request?

I wan't to download file from separate service in separate window, but the service can response with 200, 404 and 409. I need to properly handle this response code in main window.

Also if there is any cross browser solution?

Comment: You probably want to use a server side proxy to make the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, [no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14654710/2535504). Response codes are not included in the `window` object.

The only JavaScript solution to your problem using `window.open` would be if your service returns a copy of status codes in the document body. You could then parse that with (ES6):

```
const foo = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com');

foo.addEventListener('load', () => {
     console.log(foo.document.body.innerHTML);
     // or
     console.log(foo.document.body.innerText);
});
```

One big caveat is both pages need to be hosted on the same domain or [you'll run into some cross-origin issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/2535504). I'm guessing this won't work for you.

An alternative solution would be creating a blob with XMLHttpRequest, saving the file to temporary storage, and then navigating the user there to download it. You would do that as follows ([adapted from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44435573/2535504)) (ES6):

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
         window.location = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    } else {
         // error handling
    }
});

xhr.send(postData);
```

This assumes you have a file that isn't normally read by the
browser, if you need to download something like an image or video, use
[the download
attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)
as seen in the related linked answer. Also, depending on what browsers
you want to support, you may need a polyfill for this solution. [See CanIUse.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls) Also note that this option
also loads files into memory, so be wary of large files.

Finally, the most obvious and simple solution was the one @charlietfl mentioned in the comments, and that's handling this server-side. Depending on what language you're using, this is fairly easy.